# Check if a website is making X http request with javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, userscripts

I've been searching for a while but all I could find was examples on how to actually make those requests...

What I'm trying to do is to check if a website is making an http request after I click a button to X site

Ex. http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/test/1.txt

I'm guessing there a way to get all the outgoing requests and then filter the list but I can't even get the requests

What I've done so far is just inserting the eventlistener to check that X button has been clicked and then is when I'd like to check for those requests.

```
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', buttonClicked, true);

function buttonClicked(){
    -->Check requests made after button is clicked.<--
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you heard about FireBug? It's an great tool for checking HTML/JS/Network stuff. You can simply trace if a page sends HTTP requests to anywhere! http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: Don't understand wath you mean with `Check requests made after button is clicked.`. Do you like to get the file?

Comment: Nowadays you don't even need Firebug. All modern browsers have these tools built in (including Firefox, just recently; the lead developer of Firebug has a new job so the Mozilla folks needed to step it up).

Comment: what do you intend to do actually? are you just capturing `<a>` clicks? or checking if they are trying to point you to as site?

Comment: @powtac i knoow you can do that, i've checked all the requests made and there are tons of them and I'm only interested in one. I just want to get the complete request url to later insert it in a webpage

Comment: you tagged grease monkey and userscripts. are you trying to intercept an event before it makes a request using a plugin/script of some sort?

Answer (score 9):

I made a basic script for this a while ago, basically you just wrap the built-in `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var oldXHR, stateChangeHandler, prop;

  oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;

  stateChangeHandler = function (evt) {
    switch (this.readyState) {
      case oldXHR.OPENED:
        console.log('Request was made', this, evt);
        break;
      case oldXHR.DONE:
        console.log('Request finished', this, evt);
        break;
    }
  };

  function newXHR() {
    var xhr = new oldXHR();
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', stateChangeHandler);
    return xhr;
  }

  // Copy original states and toString
  for (prop in oldXHR)
    newXHR[prop] = oldXHR[prop];

  window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;
})();
```