# Check GET/POST requests on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have Angular app what with controller what show some alerts after user make any actions (add/delete etc). How i can check such requests? When user make some actions backend create json array. I have to show alert only after user made request. It's single page application and all actions make without page reloading.

I found such script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766727/check-if-a-website-is-making-x-http-request-with-javascript) and it work, but is it possible to do it with AngularJS API?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var oldXHR, stateChangeHandler, prop;

  oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;

  stateChangeHandler = function (evt) {
    switch (this.readyState) {
      case oldXHR.OPENED:
        console.log('Request was made', this, evt);
        break;
      case oldXHR.DONE:
        console.log('Request finished', this, evt);
        break;
    }
  };

  function newXHR() {
    var xhr = new oldXHR();
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', stateChangeHandler);
    return xhr;
  }

  // Copy original states and toString
  for (prop in oldXHR)
    newXHR[prop] = oldXHR[prop];

  window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use the [$http interceptor](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

I have proposed an implementation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563890/angularjs-dry-http-error/20564273#20564273).

Answer (score 0):

The method $http.get as the method $http.post has two attribute/function that can be useful for you:
first the $http.get('url').success(function(){}).error(function(){})
second the $http.get('url').then(function(){}).then(function(){})

both the methods are valid for the get as for the post request, other than that they make both a promise, something really useful in the angularJS. The first one give you a switch case between the successful request and the errors, the second one can have more than two cases.